# How to determine where a request is coming from in a REST api

Tags: php, android, rest, laravel

I have an RESTful API with controllers that should return a JSON response when is being hit by my android application and a "view" when it's being hit by a web browser. I'm not even sure I'm approaching this the right way. I'm using Laravel and this is what my controller looks like

```
class TablesController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        $tables  = Table::all();

        return Response::json($tables);
    }
}
```

I need something like this

```
class TablesController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        $tables  = Table::all();

        if(beingCalledFromWebBrowser){
            return View::make('table.index')->with('tables', $tables);
        }else{ //Android 
            return Response::json($tables);
        }
    }
```

See how the responses differ from each other?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `Request::wantsJson()` like this:

```
if (Request::wantsJson()) {
    // return JSON-formatted response
} else {
    // return HTML response
}
```

Basically what `Request::wantsJson()` does is that it checks whether the `accept` header in the request is `application/json` and return true or false based on that. That means you'll need to make sure your client sends an "accept: application/json" header too.

Note that my answer here does not determine whether "a request is coming from a REST API", but rather detects if the client requests for a JSON response. My answer should still be the way to do it though, because using REST API does not necessary means requiring JSON response. REST API may return XML, HTML, etc.

---

Reference to Laravel's [Illuminate\Http\Request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L507):

```
/**
 * Determine if the current request is asking for JSON in return.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function wantsJson()
{
    $acceptable = $this->getAcceptableContentTypes();

    return isset($acceptable[0]) && $acceptable[0] == 'application/json';
}
```

Comment: thing is, I don't use ajax for all of my request when hitting the API from the browser. should I?

Comment: Right, I've amended my answer. You'll need to make sure your app asks for json by setting `accept` header in the request to "application/json". Will update in a moment of how it works internally.

Comment: It gives the error Request::wantsJson() should not be called statically. You have to call it like $request->wantsJson(). Aso remember to add 'accept': 'application/json' in your API request header

Answer (score 48):

**Note::This is for future viewers**

The approach I found convenient using a prefix `api` for api calls. In the route file use

```
Route::group('prefix'=>'api',function(){
    //handle requests by assigning controller methods here for example
    Route::get('posts', 'Api\Post\PostController@index');
}
```

In the above approach, I separate controllers for api call and web users. But if you want to use the same controller then `Laravel Request` has a convenient way. You can identify the prefix within your controller.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if( $request->is('api/*')){
        //write your logic for api call
        $user = $this->getApiUser();
    }else{
        //write your logic for web call
        $user = $this->getWebUser();
    }
}
```

**The `is` method allows you to verify that the incoming request URI matches a given pattern. You may use the `*` character as a wildcard when utilizing this method.**

Comment: Your answer is very usefull when you use a service like cloudflare. Because I noticed that when making http request with ajax the headers get changed by cloudflare and since Laravel determines whether a request expects json based on the value in the Accept header. Using $request->is('api/*') instead of $request->expectsJson() worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use this Way. you can simply identify URL being call form ( Web or API )

> Controller code

```
if ( Request::capture()->expectsJson()  )
     {  return "API Method";  }
     else
     {  return "Web Method";     }
```

> Route Code

> For api.php
> Route::post("category","CategoryController@index");

> For Web.php
> Route::get("category","CategoryController@index");

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
if ($request->wantsJson()) {
     // enter code heree
}
```

Comment: Congratulations on copying two lines from a 6 year old accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Does your app use different headers or authorization token at all? If it does, you can make a helper function to check the headers for a key. Our app sends Authorization header (for passport) while our web end uses the passport web cookie in the web session, so I just lookout for the Authorization key to know it is app:

```
if(request()->hasHeader('Authorization')){
//is from app
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of this worked for me because I had a different route structure.

One could do it like this too.

```
public function __construct(Request $request) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->isApi = $this->request->segment(1) === 'api' ? true : false;
}
```

Then in use it like this in your controller.

```
if($this->isApi){
  //do things for api view
} else {
 //do things for html view
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can easily check the route that came from either web or API with this.

if($request->route()->getPrefix() === 'api') {
   // Your logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer naming the api-route-group. In this case you can easily change the URL-prefix of the API without breaking your code.

Add a route-name-prefix in **RouteServiceProvider.php**:

```
Route::middleware('api')
    ->prefix('api')
    ->name('api.')
    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

Now if you want to check a request for being routed to any API-route use:

```
$request->routeIs('api.*')
```

or

```
request()->routeIs('api.*')
```