# Distinguish between a call from web route vs API route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In my `web.php` file, I have a route that looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getFeed');
```

And in my `api.php` file, I have a route that looks like this:

```
Route::get('feeds', 'HomeController@getFeed');
```

Notice that they both call the same method, `getFeed()`.

Is there a way to distinguish whether the call came from the web route vs the API route in the controller's method? I need to be able to return two different responses, one for the web route and one for the API route.

Here is the `HomeController.php` class:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getFeed() {
        $user = Auth::user();

        // How to check if call is from web route or API route?
        // Need to return two different responses for each scenario.
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can use `$request->url();` to get Request URL and based on request URL you can have different processing in the same function...

Comment: you can use this  Request::capture()->expectsJson(). check my link for full detail. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590590/how-to-determine-where-a-request-is-coming-from-in-a-rest-api/63788584#63788584

Answer (score 5):

All routes from api.php are automatically prefixed with 'api/'
So you can use he below code to check

```
    if (Request::is('api*')) {
        echo "request from api route";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "request from web";
        exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I use `\Request::is('api/*')`

```
if(\Request::is('api/*'))
   return 'API';
else
   return 'Non-API';
```

Alternatively you can check using the route name;

```
if(\Request::route()->getName() == 'APIFeed')
   return 'API';
else
   return 'Non-API';
```

Make sure to set the route name;

In `web.php`

```
Route::get('feeds', 'HomeController@getFeed')->name('WebFeed');
```

In `api.php`

```
Route::get('feeds', 'HomeController@getFeed')->name('APIFeed');
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this line
    Route::get('feeds', 'HomeController@getFeed'); 
with 
    Route::get('api/feeds', 'HomeController@getFeed');

means add api prefix in all of your api routes.

it will help you to identify which route come from api and which not.

to check you can use below code

```
if (Request::is('api*')) {
    echo "request from api route";
    exit();
}else{
    echo "request from web";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$currentRoute = Illuminate\Routing\Router::getCurrentRoute(); // Returns a Route
$currentRoute->uri(); // returns the uri of the cureent route
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_getCurrentRoute

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your shoes, I would have created 3 controllers to handle the requests and like Niraj proposed, separate routes by prefix the api route with /api/

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
  public function getFeed(entrypoint) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    // do the common magic here ...
  }
}


class WebHomeController extends HomeController 
{
    public function getFeed() {
        feed = this.getFeed();
        // do the crazy web magic here ...
    }
}

class APIHomeController extends HomeController 
{
    public function getFeed() {
        feed = this.getFeed();
        // do the crazy api magic here ...
    }
}

Route::get('feeds', 'WebHomeController@getFeed'); 
Route::get('api/feeds', 'APIHomeController@getFeed');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you access parent methods from child controller

```
class WebHomeController extends HomeController 
{
    //get parent methods and protected variables
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function getFeed() {
        //access parent method
        $p = $this->getFeed();
        
        feed = this.getFeed();
        // do the crazy web magic here ...
    }
}
```