# Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object in __construct() laravel 6.18.13

Tags: laravel

I need to check whether a controller function is called from internal views or from apis so I did

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        if (Auth::user()) {
            return 'auth';
        }
        else {
            return 'client';
        }
    });
}
```

but it gives me this error Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object  in __construct()

and my middleware route looks like

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'client' => CheckClientCredentials::class,
];
```

The CheckClientCredentials class is as follows

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\MissingScopeException;

class CheckClientCredentials extends CheckCredentials
{

    protected function validateCredentials($token)
    {
        if (! $token) {
            throw new AuthenticationException;
        }
    }


    protected function validateScopes($token, $scopes)
    {
        if (in_array('*', $token->scopes)) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($scopes as $scope) {
            if ($token->cant($scope)) {
                throw new MissingScopeException($scope);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to laravel please enlighten me.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here. Can you explain more? Do you want to distinguish between a call from web route vs API route?

Comment: Yes sir that is all i want.

Comment: and if it if from web route i need to use $this->middleware('auth') and if its api route $this->middleware('client')

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383698/distinguish-between-a-call-from-web-route-vs-api-route/43384277

Comment: I already checked that and it didnt solved my problem because its useful for normal functions inside controller but i need to modify __construct() function to set middleware as per the route.

Answer (score 0):

The middleware should return: redirect('route/url') or proceed further (return $next($request))

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

    //if user is authenticated via api passport
    if (auth('api')->user()) {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');

    } 

    //if user is authenticated via web
    else if(auth()->user()) {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    // when user is not authenticated  
    else {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
    return $next($request);
});
```

Comment: I tried it but even without bearer token it is letting client to post on my database.

Comment: So it depend on your client middleware logic. What technique you have used in client middleware?

Comment: Sir, please have a look in the above edited code. I have used laravel passport for authentication.

Comment: if you are using passport , you can use $this->middleware('auth:api) and redirect if user is not authenticated. I have updated my answer, kindly check it.